# Ignoring IconDensities lint warning for specific files

Tags: android, lint

I am trying to ignore the IconDensities lint warning for some specific files.

This is the lint warning that I get:

```
Usability:Icons
1   warning IconDensities: Icon densities validation

Icon densities validation
../../../src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi: Missing the following drawables in drawable-xxhdpi: 
my_image_1.png, my_image_2.png, my_image_3.png, my_image_4.png, my_image_5.png... (22 more)
```

Now, let's say I only want to ignore the warning for the first file `my_image_1.png`, but not the others.

I have a `lint.xml` file that defines lint rule exceptions:

```
<lint>
    ...

    <issue id="IconDensities">
        <ignore path="src/**/res/drawable-xxhdpi/my_image_1.png" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Unfortunately this does not work and the file still shows up in the warning. If I use `regexp` instead of the `path`, then all files get ignored.

Btw: i know I *should* fix it by providing the file in all densities, but that is not what I am looking for right now.

Edit 01/18/2019:

Looking at the class that actually performs the lint check [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/IconDetector.java), I don't see anything in there that would make it possible to ignore a single file. So this might just really not be possible :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting the ignore path slightly differently?

```
<issue id="IconDensities">
    <ignore path="**/res/drawable-xxhdpi/my_image_1.png"/>
</issue>
```

The ignore path pointing to the wrong place seems a likely reason for it to still show up in a warning!

Comment: I think I have tried all different variations of the ignore path that I could come up with. None has worked so far. This one neither. I've also tried to add this same path for all densities at the same time (mdpi to xxxhdpi), but still no success.

Comment: That's really odd, I'm using exactly that in a project successfully right now. Are you perhaps in the wrong.. module / ignore file? Are other rules in there working?

Comment: No it's the right file. If I change the ignore to `regexp` or if i ignore the type completely then the warning goes away, but then I'll ignore all warnings of course which is not what i want.